# I can't seem to comprehend autofs

Tags: nfs, autofs

I have a NFS server on which I export the following:

```
/exports/netapps *.*.*.*/16(ro,async,root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

This folder has a bunch of sub folders which should all be visible on the clients.

I want to use autofs to mount this on the clients on the following path:

```
/opt/netapps/
```

This I can do, but when I do so the folder /opt becomes unusable, because automounter is doing something to it. I can't create new subfolder for /opt or do anything actually... I get 'Permission denied' on everything... as root!

My files:

```
cat /etc/auto.master.d/opt.autofs 
/opt file:/etc/auto.opt --timeout 10

cat /etc/auto.opt 
netapps     -fstype=nfs4    lwp16.service.rug.nl:/netapps
```

What have I done wrong? How do I solve this? Does anyone have an idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Your current `opt.autofs` file basically tells autofs to take control of the `/opt` directory, so that it can build arbitrary mountpoints there for automounting. I would recommend that you instead create and use a directory where you can allow autofs to be in full control -- something like `/opt/auto` (so you would end up using `/opt/auto/netapps`), or perhaps `/remote` (so you would end up using `/remote/netapps`).

For the former choice, you could simply change your `/opt.autofs` file:

```
/opt/auto file:/etc/auto.opt --timeout 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your map file (auto.opt) having incorrect export location (/exports/netapps)

nfs server:

```
cat /etc/exports
/exports/netapps *.*.*.*/16(ro,async,root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

nfs client

```
cat /etc/auto.master
....omitted lines.....
/misc  /etc/auto.misc
/opt   /etc/auto.opt --timeout 10
....omitted lines.....

cat /etc/auto.opt 
netapps     -ro,nfsvers=3    lwp16.service.rug.nl:/exports/netapps

service nfs restart
service autofs stop
service autofs start
```

Also you may experience name resolution issues due to dns may cause this issue. In that case try ip address in your map file (ip-addr-nfs-server:/exports/netapps).

By default, nfs is mounted with version4 if none specified as mount options.